# Windows 11 Font Folder

Tags: windows, windows-11, fonts

Is it possible to change the font installation destination folder? I mean, fonts are installed in **C:\Windows\Fonts** by default, can I have them installed in **D:\Fonts**? (Windows 11)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot safely change the location of Windows *Fonts*. The folder location is defined as `%SystemRoot%\Fonts`, and I believe it needs to be there so that fonts are available while booting.

As evidence, see the screenshot of Nirsoft's [SpecialFoldersView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/special_folders_view.html).

[image: Fonts folder location]

Note that it is possible to change the location of some other special folders, such as *Pictures*. Right-click on the folder, select the *Location* tab, and "You can change where files in this folder are stored."

However, the *Fonts* folder properties does *not* have a *Location* tab, and there is no intrinsic way to change that location.

If the folder takes up too much space, you can

- Make a copy of the whole folder to D:.
- *Uninstall* the least-used fonts.
- If you ever need an esoteric font, just reinstall from D:, knowing that  copy will be stored in *C:\Windows\Fonts*.

If by some hack, e.g., to the Registry at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders` or `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Font Management`, you *were* able to change that folder's location, Windows could be unstable, eventually needing reinstallation.

Comment: I need a program, "DeepFreeze," that resets the C partition each time the computer is rebooted. This, though, also causes the fonts I need to install to delete themselves on every reboot, so I was wondering if they could be saved to D:

Comment: As mentioned above, certainly, you can copy the entire Fonts folder to the D: drive. If one or more font is uninstalled in Windows, select all you wish to be restored from the D: drive folder, right-click, and install all at once. You might even use a small PowerShell script (https://4sysops.com/archives/install-fonts-with-a-powershell-script/) to reinstall with a single click.